# Redirect only the start page to extern site all sub categories should stay

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, dns

I have a problem were I need to redirect `www.mydomain.com` to an external url `www.otherdomain.com` but I need all the subpages and urls to stay as they are (not get redirected).

Example `www.mydomain.com/testpage` should not get redirected. Is this possible?

And if so can anyone guide me what I need to write in my htaccess file for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

The following .htaccess will do the trick:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www.\mydomain\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
Rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://www.otherdomain.com/ [L,R=302]
```

It will redirect only the **base domain (root)**, all subfolders and other URLs will stay.

Reference:
https://serverfault.com/questions/58762/how-to-redirect-root-and-only-root-via-htaccess